# SQL Group but only show top record for specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT dbo.dPlaysPerDay.fkPlayerId AS Expr1, 
       sum(dbo.dPlaysPerDay.plays), 
       dbo.dWinners.pkWinnerId AS Expr2, 
       dbo.tbl_kissImages.kissImg AS Expr3, 
       dbo.dWinners.email AS Expr4, 
       dbo.tbl_kissImages.email
FROM dbo.dPlaysPerDay 
INNER JOIN dbo.dWinners ON dbo.dPlaysPerDay.fkPlayerId = dbo.dWinners.pkWinnerId 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_kissImages ON dbo.dWinners.email = dbo.tbl_kissImages.email
GROUP BY  dWinners.email, 
          dPlaysPerDay.fkPlayerId,
          dWinners.pkWinnerId, 
          tbl_kissImages.kissImg, 
          tbl_kissImages.email
ORDER BY dWinners.email
```

I have the above sql which returns a list like this:

```
54938|14|54938|output/15124.png|156|eg@googlemail.com
54938|4|54938|output/15103.png|156|eg@googlemail.com
54939|10|54939|output/15104.png|156|eg2@googlemail.com
54939|9|54939|output/15124.png|156|eg2@googlemail.com
54940|10|54940|output/15114.png|156|eg3@googlemail.com
54940|9|54940|output/15109.png|156|eg3@googlemail.com
```

I need to group this result by email adding up all of the plays (second column) for that email and only displaying the kiss image from the first record for that email address.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: How do we know which record is "first" the one with the lowest # for png?  if so Min and sum should work well and eliminate the group by for those 2 fields.  on a side note fkplayerID and pkwinnerID will always match because of the join from winners to playsper day. so you can eliminate one of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes by 1st you mean the earliest number of .png for a given email/player.

```
SELECT dbo.dPlaysPerDay.fkPlayerId AS Expr1, 
  sum(dbo.dPlaysPerDay.plays), 
  dbo.dWinners.pkWinnerId AS Expr2, 
  min(dbo.tbl_kissImages.kissImg) AS Expr3, 
  dbo.dWinners.email AS Expr4, 
  dbo.tbl_kissImages.email
FROM dbo.dPlaysPerDay 
INNER JOIN dbo.dWinners 
  ON dbo.dPlaysPerDay.fkPlayerId = dbo.dWinners.pkWinnerId 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_kissImages 
  ON dbo.dWinners.email = dbo.tbl_kissImages.email
GROUP BY  dWinners.email, 
          dPlaysPerDay.fkPlayerId,
          dWinners.pkWinnerId, 
          tbl_kissImages.email
ORDER BY dWinners.email
```